# Can someone tell me the mistake in this sql code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Declare @Random int = 1, @Bool bit = 0;

WHILE (@Bool = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Random = ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(CharID) FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._Char where LastLogout < DATEADD(DAY, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)
        IF exists (SELECT CharID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._Char WHERE CharID = @Random)
            BEGIN
                SET @Bool = 1 /*true*/
            END
    END
print @Random
```

It gives and error after the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it says that there is an syntax error near the comma. If I remove the ,0 then the `ROUND` function doesn't have enough arguments. Someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)
```

to

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)),0)
```

Comment: That indeed did it ! Thank you :)